# Erro: Referência de objeto não definida para uma instância de um objeto

Tags: c#

Estou tentando resgatar os dados de uma tela com um **Id** específico, para posteriormente gravar em outra tela, porém um erro ocorre dizendo:

> "Referência de objeto não definida para uma instância de um objeto."

```
[HttpGet]
public ActionResult Registro(int id)
{
        var model = new CombustivelViewModelRegistro();
        try
        {
            var rep = new AtribuirVeiculoRepsitorio();
            AtribuirVeiculo av = rep.ObterPorId(id);
            model.Veiculo = av.Veiculo.Matricula;
            model.Funcionario = av.Funcionario.Nome;
        }
        catch(Exception e)
        { 
            ViewBag.Mensagem = e.Message;
        }           
    return View(model);
}

[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Registro(CombustivelViewModelRegistro model)
{
    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        var c = new Combustivel();
        try
        {
            c.DataAbastecimento = model.DataAbastecimento;  
            c.DataCadastro = DateTime.Now;
            c.Kilomtragem = Convert.ToDouble(model.Kilometragem);
            c.Quantidade = model.Quantidade;
            c.IdCombustivel = model.IdCombustivel;
            c.Veiculo.Matricula = model.Veiculo;
            c.Funcionario.Nome = model.Funcionario;

            var service = new CombustivelRepositorio();
            service.Inserir(c);

            return RedirectToAction("Index");
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            ViewBag.Mensagem = e.Message;
        }
    }
    return View();
}
```

Comment: Em qual linha acontece? Provavelmente essas chamadas ao seu repositório que busca um valor pode estar retornando um null, e você esta tentando atribuir um valor a uma propriedade.

Comment: Forneça mais detalhes na sua pergunta, pois uma pergunta com o título parecido já foi respondida e dada como encerrada

Comment: O seu Veiculo esta null e você tenta atribuir um valor a Matricula dele.

Comment: sera que devo inicializar c.Veiculo = new Veiculo();
                c.Funcionario = new Funcionario();

Comment: @MAXFXavier Você ainda está recebendo o erro "Referência de objeto não definida para uma instância de um objeto"?

Answer (score 1):

Depois desta linha

```
var c = new Combustivel();
```

Você precisa instanciar uma `Veiculo` no objeto **`c`**

```
c.Veiculo = new Veiculo();
```

Você também pode alterar o construtor de `Combustivel` para sempre que uma instância for criada, criar também uma instância de `Veiculo`.

```
public class Combustivel
{
    public Combustivel()
    {
        this.Veiculo = new Veiculo();
    }

    // Propriedades da classe
}
```